# esper fixed window based on event starting time

Tags: java, performance, bigdata, esper

I am using Esper for Aggregating my Sensor Data.
Data may arrive in any interval i.e. 1 seconds to 120 seconds.
Each data point contains TimeStamp and Value.

I want Min TimeStamp, Max TimeStamp, Average value and Count of data points in 30 min window.
Start point and end point of 30 min window is fixed i.e. 01:00 am to 01:30 am, 01:30 am to 02:00 am, etc

How can I achieve this using Esper ?

Comment: I am using Java POJO and EPL.

Comment: In EPL there is a crontab timer. It works like in Unix crontab. The crontab for this would be I think "*/30, *, *, *, *". The link is http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.1.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#pattern-timer-at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Externally-timed batch window (win:ext_timed_batch) should work for you.
But its available from Esper 4.8.0 I think
http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.8.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#view-win-ext-time-batch

Answer (score 1):

Either

win:ext_timed_batch(TimeStamp.withTime(TimeStamp.getHourOfDay(), cast(TimeStamp.getMinuteOfHour()/30, int) * 30, 0, 0).toMillisec(),30 min)

Or

win:ext_timed_batch(TimeStamp.toMillisec() -(TimeStamp.toMillisec()%1800000), 30 min)
where 1800000 is the number of milliseconds for 30 mins(30*60*1000)

Answer (score 0):

So for example see "4.2.7.3. Crontab Context Condition":

`create context Every30Min start (*/30, *, *, *, *) end after 30 min;
context Every30Min select count(*) from MyEvent output snapshot when terminated;`

Comment: this cron is based on system time and timestamp within data may be delayed (due to network or other reasons ) and it will have different timestamps based on timezone.

Comment: The cron is based on time in general (and not system time). Its based on any time that you can control via external timer, however you like it.

Comment: If you have delayed data you could use "group by" and compute a 30-minute bucket in the group by expression instead.